# Syntax issue when populating an array with a fold expression

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

Yes, I can use `std::initializer_list`. Yes, even easier, I can do aggregate initialization. But how does this work? I can't seem to fold my head around C++17's fold expressions. There aren't enough examples out there.

Here's what I came up with:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct foo
{
    T arr[N];

    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr foo(Args&&... pack)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(pack) <= N, "Too many args");
        std::size_t i = 0;
        (arr[i++] = ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int, 5> a(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

**EDIT:** Compiling with latest Clang. Fold expressions are supported.

**Live example:** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/777dc32da6c54892

Comment: Shouldn't that at least be `(arr[i++] = pack...)`?

Comment: @VaughnCato Expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'pack' - so Clang complains.

Comment: As Vaughn said: "error: pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs"

Comment: Actually, I think it is `(arr[i++] = pack,...)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to fold with the comma operator, which also solves the sequencing problem.

```
(void(arr[i++] = pack) , ...);
```

Comment: Yeah, works perfectly. It's gonna take some time before this syntax becomes not confusing to me. It looks perfectly logical when someone else writes it. :D

Comment: @Jarod42 Nope, `,` handles sequencing.

Answer (score 5):

Since the comma operator is left-associative, you would ideally use a left unary fold:

```
(...,void(arr[i++] = pack))
```

The cast to `void` is to make sure that the built-in comma operator is used. In this case, the handedness doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both `((a, b), c)` and `(a, (b, c))` evaluates `a` then `b` then `c`.

Comment: @T.C.: With a (void) cast, that is true, but it seems best to get in the habit of using the proper handedness.

Comment: @T.C.: And yes, function-style cast is nicer.